# WSDL issues from Apache Tomcat to IIS7 C# web service and back to Apache Tomcat

Tags: c#, web-services, apache, iis, wsdl

I'm having some issues implimenting a vendors box within an existing environment. Their box is running Apache Tomcat and I'm running IIS7. When the WSDL file is passed from Apache to IIS, IIS responds back with an `<s:` instead of the `<xsd:` that their Apache server is wanting to see. Below is the beginning of the WSDL file that's sent. The data being returned is correct, however the format they want to see starts with `<xsd:` NOT `<s:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:ahpns="http://ws.ebc.ahp.ini.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    name="AHPEligibilityBenefitClaimsWS" targetNamespace="http://ws.ebc.ahp.ini.com/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://ws.ebc.ahp.ini.com/">
            <xsd:element name="GetClaimsDataRequest">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
```